Conditional Probability in HMM
I'm studying HMM recently, but I'm having some problems deriving the backward algorithm. The following is the derivation formula of the backward algorithm, where $\beta_{t}(j)$ represents the probability of observing the subsequent observation value $\ O_{t+1},\cdots,O_{L}$ given the state value $\ q_{j}$ at time $\ t$, $\ O_{t}$ represents the observation  at time $\ t$, $\ x_{t}$ represents the state in time $\ t$, $\ q_{j}$ represents the value of state, and $\ n$ represents the number of all states.
$$\begin{aligned}\beta_{t}(j)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(O_{t+1},\cdots,O_{L},x_{t+1}=q_{i},|x_{t}=q_{j})\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(O_{t+2},\cdots,O_{L}|x_{t}=q_{j},x_{t+1}=q_{i},O_{t+1})\cdot P(O_{t+1},x_{t+1}=q_{i}|x_{t}=q_{j})\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(O_{t+2},\cdots,O_{L}|x_{t+1}=q_{i})\cdot P(O_{t+1}|x_{t+1}=q_{i},x_{t}=q_{j})\cdot P(x_{t+1}=q_{i}|x_{t}=q_{j})\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(O_{t+2},\cdots,O_{L}|x_{t+1}=q_{i})\cdot P(O_{t+1}|x_{t+1}=q_{i})\cdot P(x_{t+1}=q_{i}|x_{t}=q_{j})\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{t+1}(i)\cdot e_{i}(O_{t+1})\cdot a_{ji}\end{aligned}$$
Besides, HMM has two important assumptions: observation independence assumption and Markov assumption, that is,

the observation value at the current moment depends only on the state at the current moment,
the state at the current moment $\ t$ is only related to the state at the previous moment $\ t-1$.

Now, my question is how to derive the following formula：
$\ P(O_{t+2},\cdots,O_{L}|x_{t}=q_{j},x_{t+1}=q_{i},O_{t+1}) = P(O_{t+2},\cdots,O_{L}|x_{t+1}=q_{i})$
